# Farming with CPU in my Lan

Tags: mining-theory, mining-hardware, miner-configuration

I have recently built an internet network for my entire condominium to use for a very cheap price, and i thought, why not farm bitcoins with it using users CPU?

I heard about coffee miners, but i need something more automatic, that doesn't need presence of a running Kali-Linux. I thought about using DNS, an html first page that injects javascript in each visited page from the AP's... but didn't figure it out yet.

Is there any way to do it?

thanks in advance

Comment: This is extremely unethical, and depending on your jurisdiction, illegal. You should not do this.

Comment: The best way to succeed at doing this would be to get a lawyer, move to a new country, or prepare for the possibility of doing hard time.

Comment: you need to clarify whether or not your getting customer's permission

Answer (score 0):

It is unethical to use other people's computers to mine without their explicit consent.  End of story.

The fact that you're providing them some other service at a discount doesn't give you the right to use their computers without their consent.  If you feel you deserve more, raise your prices.

Or, you can offer a deal: "Internet access for $XXX if you agree to let me use your computer to mine." But then you'll have no need to do this via code injection or similar hackery; just have them install the necessary software.  However, my guess is that unless your discount is quite exceptional, your clients will be unhappy as soon as they see the jump in their electricity bills.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple things here.  Shall address.

**Methodology**

The true answer here is this:  you cannot currently mine Bitcoin (and gain any kind of profit) with a CPU.  So that would be a "no" you can't with any effectiveness mine Bitcoin with a CPU.

Bitcoin runs on the SHA-256 algorithm.

CPU mining will, at this point in time, never generate any amount of usable Bitcoin.  Bitcoin mining is done with ASIC hardware.  ASIC stands for application-specific integrated circuit.  These are powerful machines that are built only and specifically to use the SHA-256 mine Bitcoin, thereby rendering other methods extremely unprofitable.

(Other coins have other ASICs that utilize that particular coin's mining algorithm.)

In another method of mining Bitcoin, people mine different coins with GPUs and then convert their earnings into Bitcoin.

**Terminology**

Farm - a farm is a group of machines that are used to mine cryptocurrency; farms can be comprised of 3 or 4 individual mining rigs or a warehouse that houses thousands of pieces of specialized cryptocurency mining equipment

Mine - mining is the process of using CPUs, GPUs and ASICs to solve algorithmic computational math problems for which they then receive a reward in a specific amount of specified cryptocurrency

So, one does not "farm" Bitcoin, one "mines" Bitcoin and may or may not have a farm to do so.

**Feasbility**

Now, whether you should or should not utilize network resources that are not your own to create a source of income without the knowledge of all parties involved would be a different question.  You can do whatever you want to do in life, "good" or "bad"-- there will just eventually be consequences that will mirror the choice that was made.  With this specific matter, there are ethical and legal ramifications at stake.